Editing Chromium Omnibox (url address bar)
I am searching for files in chromium source code to edit strings in chromium omnibox (url address bar) for example changing "not secure" to something like "insecure".
Can you help?
According to some sources I have tried to locate proper function and file where the text not secure is generated, not able to find the correct place.
error_classification.cc security_state.cc omnibox_edit_model.cc

The thing is if you can do that, you could also make it say "secure" .. which would be a problem.  Imagine building whole algorithms to hash values to just be able to edit one variable to bypass telling the user if the data is secure or man in the middle ready?

components/omnibox_strings.grdp:44 and components/omnibox_strings.grdp:49 but neither of them is "not secure".

I've been searching the wrong place whole time. thank you for answering sir!!
